# Remote access Windows Vista to Mac OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

Is there a means to do remote desktop access from Windows Vista to Mac Mini with OSX?
Looking to be able to remote in to Mac in order to access system so no need to have it on a seperate monitor/kb to do testing and development.

Anything similar to Windows Remote Desktop that can be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**VNC for OS X**](http://macapper.com/2007/03/19/vnc-remote-desktop-for-free/)

*NOTE*: VNC server is already included with OS X 10.4 and later. See http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X:

1. Open your System Preferences from your blue apple menu.
2. Click the Sharing tab under 'Internet and Network'.
3. Click Start to fire up the Remote Desktop component.
4. Click Access Privileges to open the more advanced options.
5. Check on VNC viewers may control screen with password and define a password.
6. You can close the System Preferences. You're done!

Comment: two steps ahead of me. VNC is the best! :)

Comment: Ooh. Didn't know there was a free one out there.

Comment: Looks like this may be the best/only option.  I don't need web based access, both Mac and PC will be on a local netowrk.

Comment: So what is the best free VNC client for Windows Vista to connect to the OSX server?

Comment: @schooner - I don't use VNC much and I still run XP, so I am not sure if there are better options but I used to always use TightVNC - http://www.tightvnc.com/

Comment: I tied TightVNC and UltraVNC and the performance was poor, bit laggy on the screenupdates.  I'm use to RDC on Windows which seems almost realtime, VNC on the same netowrk was really unsuable.  Not sure if it is a setting or what.

Comment: I think TeemViewer ist the best. You can also access your client from the web, from any pc ,mac or linux machiene, even from your mobile. http://www.teamviewer.com/de/download/

Answer (score 1):

Is something like [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) useful? There's a free version that doesn't have sound or file transport. If you can do without sound and have another way of sending files it might work. Or you can purchase a paid version...

Answer (score 0):

VNC won't send a Ctrl+Drag event, so its usefulness for something like Interface Builder is nil...  I've been looking for a remoting program that *will* send a Ctrl+Drag; if anyone has developed using Interface Builder remotely, I'm very interested.  (Mac Mini, being controlled by XP SP3; have tried TightVNC, UltraVNC, several others -- prefer a free solution but would be willing to pay at this point.)

Comment: Luckily the Ctrl+drag functionality is not the only way to create  connection between the elements: A right click brings up a list of delegates/events for an interface element, and clicking and dragging the circle to the right of those events to the appropriate delegate objects allows me to link elements with Outlets, Events with Actions, delegates with responders etc. http://codingincircles.com/2010/01/developing-remotely/

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) which provides a very seamless experience, especially if the systems are on the same internal network and have their own monitors on your desk.

Comment: Synergy doesn't share screens, it just provides a seamless transition for the mouse and keyboard across machines with their own monitors.

Answer (score 0):

logmein would definitely be the best solution here, otherwise use VNC